# Error when Deploy in Xamarin Blank App Android App

Tags: c#, android, deployment, xamarin, mono

I have big trouble with deploy (`debug`) a blank `Android` app (I try this also with few samples) on phone `Motorolla TC55`.

When loading `API 21` platform framework I have this error:

> deployment failed because of an internal error: Unexpected install
>   output: pkg: Mono.Android.Platform.apk.

I use VS2013 but in the XS I have same error.

Comment: post the full log message..

Comment: Which OS version do you've installed on your TC55? This device is currently available with Android v4.1 (API level 16) and Android v4.4 (API level 19). You can try to change the target API level of your project. I've the exact same setup and I don't see this issue.